# Make some space in Sharepoint office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

"I have SharePoint office 365 online and there are few sites in the SharePoint and now I got the message that **This site is almost out of storage space. To free up space, delete files you do not need and empty the recycle bin**.So I deleted items from Recycle Bin to create the space, but it does not help me much except to create some Mb space in SharePoint.  So my question is that  I have many videos in my SharePoint site those I can move somewhere in SharePoint or in office 365 but I do not want to delete any of those videos and user can see anytime when they want. So how can I make the space in SharePoint.  Looking forward to have your ideas.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following 2 methods to see if the issue can be solved.

Method 1. Change the site collection storage management to automatic(In SharePoint admin center > site collections, make sure you have enough space for your site. Then try below method):

1. Go to SharePoint admin center -> settings.
2. Set Site Collection Storage Management to Automatic.

Method 2. Use PowerShell to set the site collection's storage quota manually.

1. Set up the **SharePoint Online Management Shell Windows PowerShell** environment.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps

2. Run **SharePoint Online Management Shell** as administrator.
3. Run **Connect-SPOService** and enter your SharePoint admin center’s URL and your admin credentials.
4. Run the following command to change the site collection’s storage quota:

   Set-SPOSite -Identity  -StorageQuota 1048576

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay.  My question  is the site is already managed and there are videos file which we want to move somewhere else so It cam make in our site but user should be able to see those files. Thanks again!!

Comment: You can create a new site to keep the files and allow anonymous access in this new site so that users should still be able to see these files.

Comment: Really good idea, Thansk again!

Comment: If you think my suggestion is helpful, you could accept it as an answer.